# iPython lprun not printing output

Tags: python, ipython

I don't know what's going on here, so thought I would ask you guys.

I just installed iPython 3.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.2

In iPython I tried my function with no results, but here is an example:

```
In [21]: def rn():
   ....:     for ix in range(0,100): print ix
   ....:

In [22]: %lprun rn()
0
1
2
3
4
....
98
99
Timer unit: 1e-06 s
```

In this type of situation I'm expecting a normal cProfile type output, showing the lines that ran and how long each one took. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag to get line by line output:

```
%lprun -f rn  rn()
```

Output:

```
In [13]: %lprun -f rn  rn()
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
94
95
96
97
98
99
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.000933 s
File: <ipython-input-4-00cddd5336b9>
Function: rn at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def rn():
     2       101          933      9.2    100.0        for ix in range(0,100): print ix
```

Comment: Beautiful. Is there a way to sort by % Time? Also is there a way to have it also profile any other functions ran from my same file? So say I've got run(), iterate(), etc in example.py and run() is the main function. Is there a way to call run() but also include profiling for iterate() ?

Comment: @user1610719, not as far as I know, prun takes a sort key but I don't think lprun does.

Comment: why 'rn rn()'? instead of just 'rn()'?

Comment: Didn't work for me - just got a blank newline above my result.